# How to debug web app on windows mobile (7 and later)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, mobile, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I debug Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198808/how-do-i-debug-internet-explorer-on-windows-phone-7)

I have build a mobile web app. It works well in android and iphone, but not on windows phone 7. I would like to debug javascript for windows phone 7. What tools can I use to debug the issue?