# How to debug a website on Windows Phone? [not remote debug]

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, windows-phone

I am a web developer and would like to debug a webapp/website on a Windows Phone device. It would be neat to have some kind of window where I can see the javascript console.

I know how to get the console window on both Android (about:debug) and iOS (Developer console), but I have not yet figured out how on Windows Phone. Is it possibible, and if so, how?

EDIT:
What I am looking for is ***not remote*** debugging. I am looking for a **debug console on the actual device**.

Comment: Have you checked: http://sgrebnov.github.com/IeMobileDebugger/ ?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for debugging on the actual device

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Have found this article a few days ago, it might be the closest solution in your case: http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.ru/2013/03/how-to-debug-windows-phone-html5-apps.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.5+ (IE9) and 8 (IE10) doesn't have a debug console but it's possible to add it to your web app via [JSConsole](https://github.com/remy/jsconsole) by [Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/).

Setting up a remote debugging session is straight forward enough. Visit [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/), get a unique session ID, add the session ID and JS snippet to your web app and you're good to go. More detailed [setup instructions and video can be found on the website](http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html).

And although the JSConsole instructions doesn't explicitly mention Windows Phone support, [a number of websites](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/netpontonews/CtPS2ghk-Jk/2LQHw1Mm9BcJ) [have confirmed it works](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/347777/How-to-create-HTML5-apps-on-Windows-Phone-with-Pho#pre4).

Other tools, which may also be of use, are mentioned on a [previous Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198808/how-do-i-debug-internet-explorer-on-windows-phone-7).

**UPDATE:** [Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) introduces a new emulation tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows local (assuming you're running Windows 8.1) testing and debugging of websites for Windows Phone.

Comment: Are you sure there is no such console on Windows Phone? Feels like such a basic function...

Comment: Yes, I checked on both the WP8 emulator and real WP8 device. And although iOS and Android have remote debugging, the feature is quite new (only since iOS 6, I think). We might see a remote debugging feature for IE on WP8 in the future - the WP team have publicly stated that they ran out of time when it came to certain WP8 features. Let's hope they appear in an update due later in the year!

Comment: iOS always had their debug console on the phone and I think Android always have had it as well. 
I am looking for a way to debug the website on the phone. Remote debugging will not help me if I want to know what has happened on the users phone, as long as their devices are not on remote debugging or I have a log on their sessions.

Comment: I mentioned a few other tools (linked via a previous answer), have you tried [http://sgrebnov.github.com/IeMobileDebugger/](IE Mobile Debugger)? it appears to have an in-app console. If this works for you, I can amend my answer.

Comment: That is basicly Wienre and it is still a remote debugging tool. It is good, but what I am looking for is a debug console on the actual phone. But, it seems that I am asking for something that isn't there... :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no built-in console in the current release of Windows Phone 8. Also, Microsoft is getting secretive about their updates so we have no idea what's coming in the next update.

Comment: i cannot reproduce some bugs using the emulator. it is maybe one of the scariest emulators out there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. But you can use IE10 and change the User Agent string to simulate you are IE10 in Windows Phone.

**Edit**

I think all JavaScript functions in the mobile are supported in Desktop. But if it is not a solution I'm afraid your only friend is this :
[Compact Inspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/27/ie9-compat-inspector.aspx)

Comment: Do you think all the javascript functions in the desktop version of IE10 is supported in the mobile version?

Comment: When I use the phone I would like to know what is going on behind the scenes. A simulation wouldn't help me with that...

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to test the website against desktop IE10 with all JavaScript/DOM debugging support you got there - it's 99% similar to IE10 in Windows Phone 8. For additional testing on phone you can install the [Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us) and launch the website on the emulator.
Edit: nice article [How to debug Windows Phone HTML5 Apps](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.cz/2013/03/how-to-debug-windows-phone-html5-apps.html) using Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[Weinre][1]` with `VS2012` / `VS2013` phone emulators or an actual device.
You have all the details here, very simple to set up nodeJS based solution.

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.cz/2013/03/how-to-debug-windows-phone-html5-apps.html