# How to simulate Windows Phone browser?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, responsive-design

I'm creating some page using `responsible web design` so I get some problem. My page works correct on each desktop browsers (after change screen resolution) and on IPhone.

But it have problem on `Windows Phone`. So I want to check what is wrong but I cannot duplicate my problem on desktop browser when I use custom `user agent` from my phone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; 
IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 710)
```

Is there an emulator (for Windows Phone) which have some `developer tool` like Chrome's one?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean a windows phone emulator?

Comment: There is WP emulator, but it does not contain any developer tools within it's browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198808/how-do-i-debug-internet-explorer-on-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this out (HTML Debugger).](http://sgrebnov.github.com/IeMobileDebugger/) I am sure it'll help you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I run this app and write my url and click "debug" I get Alert with some uri but when I go on it on my desktop browser it doesn't work.